# Overriding default Redirect View in Spring Social

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, twitter, spring-social

I'm trying to override the default behavior of Spring Social to redirect to "connect/{providerId}Connected" once connected to a provider (Twitter, Facebook etc).

So I'm trying to override the default behavior by overriding the method **protected java.lang.String connectedView(java.lang.String providerId)**

So I've subclassed ConnectController and tried overriding:

```
@Controller
public class CustomConnectController extends ConnectController{

    @Inject
    public CustomConnectController(
            ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator,
            ConnectionRepository connectionRepository) {
        super(connectionFactoryLocator, connectionRepository);
    }


    @Override
    protected String connectedView(String providerId){
        //Do some logic

        return "redirect:/foo/bar;
    }

}
```

See documentation of the controller class: http://static.springsource.org/spring-social/docs/1.0.x/api/org/springframework/social/connect/web/ConnectController.html

But I get the following error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping found.
>   Cannot map
>   'org.springframework.social.connect.web.ConnectController#0' bean
>   method  public org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView
>   org.springframework.social.connect.web.ConnectController.connect(java.lang.String,org.springframework.web.context.request.NativeWebRequest)
>   to
>   {[/connect/{providerId}],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}:
>   There is already 'customConnectController' bean method public
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView
>   org.springframework.social.connect.web.ConnectController.connect(java.lang.String,org.springframework.web.context.request.NativeWebRequest)
>   mapped.

Can anyone please guide.
My requirement is as follows:
1. After user connects social account (Twitter, Facebook etc)
2. Do some business logic
3. Redirect to /foo/bar page

Please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution myself.
Posting the answer for everyone, so that anyone struggling with the silly thing might be benefited:

Actually I had ConnectController configured in my Config & now the custom controller was stepping on that & hence it says already mapped. Removing the config from the config solves the problem.

In my case removing the following code:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.social.connect.web.ConnectController">
        relies on by-type autowiring for the constructor-args
        <property name="applicationUrl" value="${application.url}" />
    </bean>
```

Comment: Thanks for your own answer, I tried to figure out how to do it with JavaConfig + spring boot but cannot make it work

Answer (score 0):

Well You have done everything right but have forgotten to add

```
    @RequestMapping("/connect")
```

In case you are working with Spring boot and doesn't have and spring-config.xml files you can use below code.

This code did the trick for me

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/connect")
public class ChangeDefaultFlowController extends ConnectController {

    public ChangeDefaultFlowController(ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator,
            ConnectionRepository connectionRepository) {
        super(connectionFactoryLocator, connectionRepository);
    }

    @Override
    protected String connectedView(String providerId) {
        return "redirect:/"+providerId;
    }

}
```

[This Link offers more explanation on changing the redirect flow to page or another rest controller](http://littlebigextra.com/how-to-change-the-default-spring-social-redirect-flow/)